# php checking the format of a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to verify if a string is properly formatted.  Below are a few of the formats that come through. These are just random typed items.

```
1abc.abc

ab2.abc

abc.abc.abt

aerj/adfa.tht
```

The before the . can be symbols alpha and numeric. After the . The check im trying to do is check the end of the string for the . followed by no more than 4 alpha characters.  I believe this can be done with regex but I do not know where to start on it.

An invalid string is anything containing numbers, symbols or greater than 4 characters following the period

Comment: Please look up regular expressions.

Comment: and or give a good example of a valid string and an invalid string

Comment: an invalid string is anything with symbols, numbers or longer than 4 characters following the .

Comment: Would `abc.` be valid? How about `.`?  or `.abc`?

Comment: There must be something before and after the period

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go with regex pattern `/\.[a-zA-Z]{0,4}$/`

Answer (score 3):

Try this (match all alphanumeric/symbols, but no spaces):

```
^([\S]+)\.([A-Za-z]{0,4})$
```

Same, but with spaces matched:

```
^(.*?)+\.([A-Za-z]{0,4})$
```

More specifically:

```
if (preg_match("/^([\S]+)\.([A-Za-z]{0,4})$/", $yourStr) == 1) { }
```

Comment: `.` matches anything, not just alphanumeric.

Comment: He said symbols, alpha, and number.  I guess it would match spaces too, though...

Comment: I'm an idiot and completely read over symbols by accident. Although yeah, matches spaces ;)

Comment: In which case, use `\w` (or `\W`, whichever is not whitespace).

Comment: There is still one issue.  In the instance of "abc.abc.abt" it fails

Comment: If you remove the question mark from the second example it will fix it.  It turns it from a "non-greedy" to a "greedy" check.